# Automatic script discovery with fs module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to develop REST API with Node.js. I want to separate routes and specific resource modules, to standardize the organization of resources, have different API versions. I also want to avoid defining new routes each time I developed a corresponding resource module. So I want my routing to automatically discover all my scripts in a directory where all the resource modules are located. I am doing this by leveraging `fs` module. My question, however is about a performance of such an approach. Each request to my server will involve these file system lookups, and I am not sure how bad it will impact a performance. Is there any better way to achieve, what I am trying to achieve?

**A middleware that handles different API version subdirectories**

```
    const versionRouter = (req, res, next) => {
      fs.readdir(__dirname, function(err, items) {
        console.log(items);
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          if (items[i] != "index.js") {
            console.log(items[i]);
            let version = items[i];
            const express = require("express");
            let expressRouter = express.Router();
            expressRouter = controllerRouterMiddleware(expressRouter, version);
            app.use(uriPrefix + "/" + version, expressRouter);
          }
        }
        next();
      });
    };
```

**A middleware that scans for resource controllers in specific version subdirectory and creates following routes:**

- GET /resource resolves to controller.list method
- POST /resource resolves to controller.create method
- GET /resource/:id resolves to controller.item method
- PUT /resource/:id resolves to controller.save method
- DELETE /resource/:id resolves to controller.delete method

```
    const controllerRouterMiddleware = (expressRouter, version) => {
      let items = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/" + version);
      console.log(__dirname + "/" + version);
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log(items[i]);
        const apiController = require("./" + version + "/" + items[i]);
        expressRouter
          .route("/" + items[i].slice(0, -3))
          .get(apiController.list)
          .post(apiController.create);

        expressRouter
          .route("/" + items[i].slice(0, -3) + "/:id")
          .get(apiController.item)
          .put(apiController.save)
          .delete(apiController.delete);
      }
      return expressRouter;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way to do this with the idea proposed by [Mohit Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266549/mohit-sahu)
Basically I created a generic route by using express router parameters, that accepts all the HTTP methods. Then created a proxy method that imports corresponding controller and invokes specific method depending on parameters and request method.

```
    const controllerProxy = (req, res, next) => {
      let v = req.params.v;
      let resource = req.params.resource;
      let operation = req.params.operation || undefined;

      const controller = require("./" + v + "/" + resource);
      if (req.method == "GET") {
        if (operation != undefined) {
          return controller.item(req, res, next);
        } else {
          return controller.list(req, res, next);
        }
      }
      if (req.method == "POST") {
        return controller.create(req, res, next);
      }
      if (req.method == "PUT" && operation != undefined) {
        return controller.save(req, res, next);
      }
      if (req.method == "DELETE" && operation != undefined) {
        return controller.delete(req, res, next);
      }
    };

    return (req, res, next) => {
      app.route(uriPrefix + "/:v/:resource/:operation?").all(controllerProxy);
      next();
    };
```

Used that piece of code as a middleware for my express app instance.
No `fs` lookups now. Works perfectly well!

Answer (score 0):

try using regex in routing path :

```
app.get('/:var(v1|v2)/x/y',controller.function);
```

Comment: I will still need to import my controller manually. What I am trying to do is to make router to automatically discover and import controllers by looking up the controllers directory. But that lookup happens on every request.